# if you add "not" before a dependent clause does it become an independent clause?

Tags: negation

Original sentence: "I will go to school, but not when it is snowing."

If "not" serves as a substitute for the negative clause as "I will not go school", then I see 2 independent clauses:

Interpretation: "I will go to school, but I will not go to school when it is snowing. "

So if I pause after speaking and then add an additional dependent clause-------if my homework is complete. So that the original sentence becomes----"I will go to school, but not if it snowing, if my homework is complete."

Does the "if my homework is complete" apply to "I will go to school" or "I will not go to school when it is snowing" or both?

Comment: Rearrange the position of the clauses: If my homework is complete, I will go to school but not if it is snowing. Now, when you read it, what do you think—does the condition, "if my homework is complete" apply to going to school or the snowing situation?

Comment: it appears to apply to both....I am questioning if it is possible for it to apply to part of and not the whole statement before it? If not, then why?

Comment: As in the repeated duplicates.  "I will go to school, but not if it snowing, if my homework is complete." is ungrammatical and, moreover meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

*I will go to school, but not if it is snowing, if my homework is complete.*

This sentence has one main clause and two conditional clauses.

*Main clause*: I will go to school;
*Conditional clause 1*:  **but not if** it is snowing;
*Conditional clause 2*: **if** my homework is complete

The sentence says, you will go to school only if you finish your homework **AND** if it doesn't snow. If the either of the two isn't true, you may not go to school.

Both the conditions have to be satisfied for you to go to school.