# what is "not" serving as?

Tags: negation, if

> I will go to the beach, but not if it is raining.

What is the independent clause(s) in the above sentence to which "if it is raining" is/are attaching to.

Is "not" serving as the independent clause "I will not go to the beach" to which "if it is raining" is attaching to? Or is it serving as a negative adverbial phrase "will not go to the beach"?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278344/if-you-add-not-before-a-dependent-clause-does-it-become-an-independent-clause

Answer (score 1):

The negation is applying to the "if". If the condition ("it is raining") is true, then the statement is false, and if the condition is false, the statement is true.

In other words, "not if" is synonymous with "unless".